# Storing two separate values from an array into a single array index in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, chars

For instance, Let's say I have the following:

```
char str[] = "33MayPen5";
int length = strlen(str);
char buffer[length];
int j = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    buffer[j] = // I would like to read the number 33 from str and store it in buffer[0]
    j++;
}
```

Basically, I would like to store str[0] AND str[1] which is 33, into buffer[0]. How would I accomplish such a task? Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Are you able to use the String class at all?

Comment: You must be more precise. Do you want to convert "33" to the 33 char value ? And for "Ma" ? Do you want the sum of ASCII code ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide code which is correctly formed, you have an error on this line:

```
char buffer[length];
```

You lenght must be const.
You can solve this by reading each nomber and convert it to int. But no way to store 33 at once.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you need something as

```
char str[] = "33MayPen5";
int length = strlen(str);
char *buffer = new char[length];
int j = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < length && std::isdigit( str[i] ); i++ ) 
{

    buffer[j++] = str[i];
}
```

Or if you need to store all digits from str in buffer then the loop can look as

```
for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
{

    if ( std::isdigit( str[i] ) ) buffer[j++] = str[i];
}
```

Of course it would be better if you would use std::string instead of the dynamically allocated array.

In this case the both examples would look as

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.reserve( length );

for ( int i = 0; i < length && std::isdigit( str[i] ); i++ ) 
{
    buffer.push_back( str[i] );
}
```

and

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.reserve( length );

for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
{

    if ( std::isdigit( str[i] ) ) buffer.push_back( str[i] );
}
```

**EDIT:** I see you changed your post.

When the code could look as

```
char str[] = "33MayPen5";
int length = strlen(str);
unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[length];

unsigned char c = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < length && std::isdigit( str[i] ); i++ ) 
{

    c = c * 10 + str[i];
}
buffer[0] = c;
```

Comment: -1, too hasty post? you can't declare a buffer of variable size ;)

Comment: @Casper Von B A good remark. I did not even take into account that he uses non-const expression.

Comment: i think u should use memory dynamic allocation with pointers. to be able to reserve a memory space as you need at run time.

Comment: Removed my downvote after editing, but still there is too much speculation for this too be a useful Q&A